# Allow promotion of job in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline which is responsible for about 5 stages (build and several different tests). I'm migrating from Jenkins 1.XX (with no pipelines) to Jenkins 2 and I'd like to replicate my process as closely as possible. The pipeline job I have set up on J2 handles everything exactly the same except it's using a JenkinsFile. The only issue is that the pipeline plugin does not appear to support Promotion of particular builds like you can do with Freestyle Jobs. Has anyone found a way around this?

Comment: Is your main use-case deploying the last build? Or do you need a system for deploying previous builds? Although I haven't found a way to `Promote`, the value returned from [building jobs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) can be used to at least [copyArtifacts](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/), using the build number as the `selector` argument. Then I run my own "promotion" (bash scripts specific to each job), that deploy the artifact to its final destination.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like Promoted Builds Plugin [doesn't support pipelines yet](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36089). If you check the issue there is also some good pros and cons about supporting it for pipelines.