# How to promote one job from other in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I want to promote one job(A) from another job(B) in jenkins once job B is successful. Was checking out if there is some "Promote Another Job Plugin" exist or not to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to best use this plugin: 
[Jenkins Parameterized Trigger plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger/)

*You will need to use this in Post-build Actions in Jenkins job(B) which will trigger job(A)

Comment: My aim is not to trigger job A from post build of Job B, instead i want to promote Job A from job B only once B is complete.

Comment: There are multiple options in post build trigger and you can choose any one of them. There is also a choice only after the successful completion of job, in your case successful completion of job(B), job(A) will be triggered.

Comment: Only after successful completion of job B, i want to just promote job A and not execute it since its already executed.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [Allow promotion of job in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257766/allow-promotion-of-job-in-jenkins-pipeline) there is a [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/promoted-builds/) which does not support delclarative pipelines. So if you do not use a declarative pipeline it could work for you.